# && Operation in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, logical-operators

Which one out of the following two should be preferred while doing && operation on two values.

```
 if (!StartTime.Equals(DateTime.MinValue) &&
    !CreationTime.Equals(DateTime.MinValue))
```

Or

```
     if (!(StartTime.Equals(DateTime.MinValue) && CreationTime.Equals(DateTime.MinValue))
```

What is the difference between the two?

Comment: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally I use the former, I find it easier to read if as much information as possible is as close to the point I need it as possible.

For instance, just now I was wondering if your question was whether it was better to put the expression on two lines or just one, until I noticed the part about the not and the parenthesis.

That is, provided they mean the same, which your expressions doesn't.

ie.

```
if (!a && !b)
```

is not the same as:

```
if (!(a && b))
```

Rather:

```
if (!(a || b))
```

Answer (score 13):

```
(Not A)  AND  (Not B)
```

is **NOT** equal to

```
Not (A And B)
```

Comment: Indeed, looks like De Morgan's laws got sidetracked.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends what you want.  They both do different things, and either might be correct in the given context.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding only the formatting, I prefere:

```
if(MyFirstExtremlyLongExpressionWhichBarelyFitsIntoALine
  && MySecondExtremlyLongExpressionWhichBarelyFitsIntoALine
  && MyThirdExtremlyLongExpressionWhichBarelyFitsIntoALine
) {
  // ...
}
```

But if the expressions are really long and compley, you should define temporary variables to enhance readability:

```
bool condition1 = MyFirstExtremlyLongExpressionWhichBarelyFitsIntoALine;
bool condition2 = MySecondExtremlyLongExpressionWhichBarelyFitsIntoALine;
bool condition3 = MyThirdExtremlyLongExpressionWhichBarelyFitsIntoALine;

if(condition1 && condition2 && condition3) {
  // ...
}
```

The latter also clarifies your intention, if you are doing more complex boolean expressions:

```
if((!condition1 && !condition2) && condition3) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first one is much more readable, and readability is the most important thing here.

Is the second one actually equivelent to the first statement? Shouldn't it be ||?

Answer (score 0):

If you give put in the values you will see

(!1 && !1)  == (0 && 0) == 0
(!1 && !0)  == (0 && 1) == 0

!(1 && 1)  == !1 == 0
!(1 && 0)  == !0 == 1